# How to override tags - bootstrap css scaffolding.less

Tags: html, css, styles

I can't override HTML tags using my own styles. For example if I add new css rule for ***hr*** tag then I see both rules. I want to use my custom rule.

**html**

```html
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <style type="text/css">

                p {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    width: 150px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-left: 18px;
                }
                .testbox {
                    margin: 20px auto;
                    width: 343px;
                    height: 244px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 8px/7px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 8px/7px;
                    border-radius: 8px/7px;
                    background-color: #ebebeb;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);
                    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);
                    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);
                    border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
                }

               .box1 {
                    color: #a9a9a9;
                    opacity: 0.3;
                }
              </style>

<div class="testbox">
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <form action="/">
        <hr class="box1">
        <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-envelope "></i></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Kod" required/>
        <p>By clicking Register, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Register</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

in order to override a style you need to specify all the styles you need to overite in your class selector. or use a general element selector to override.

e.g.

```
hr {
    ...
}
```

a more powerful approach is to do:

```
hr {
    all: unset;
}
```

witch resets all the styling to `inherent` or `initial`

Comment: I want use default style rules but sometimes I want use my own.

Comment: so I suggest using a class to override and change a specific instance of use.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds the following rules to `<hr>` as part of its framework:

```
margin-top: 1rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);

box-sizing: content-box;
height: 0;
overflow: visible;
```

if you don't want these rules to apply (but still want to use Bootstrap), then you must overwrite each rule that you don't want to have applied. You can always set the individual property to the *default* value in this regard, which will give you the same effect as with Bootstrap not having applied their styling to the tag in the first place. This can be done by setting a value of `initial`.

It's worth noting that you'll need to apply more [*specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than Bootstrap. Bootstrap only applies the root `hr` styling, so your `.box1` rule should override this due to higher specificity. However, you can always increase this if need be, with something like `hr.box1`.

It's also worth noting that `color` does **not** apply to `<hr>` elements; you need to set the colour in `border-top`'s `rgb()` value instead.

The selector `.box1` can be seen overwriting Bootstrap's `hr` colour in the following:

```css
/* Bootstrap

hr {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

*/

.box1 {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<hr class="box1">
```